# How to remove Image location showing in body although it is in a Meta Tag

Tags: python, django, meta-tags

I have a Django project and I added an Image meta tag as following in the base.html

```
    <meta property="og:image" content="{% block image %}{% endblock %}">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="300">
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="300">
```

in the home.html page I have added the following:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %} {% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% block description %}{{ info.description }}{% endblock %}
{% block image %}{{ info.avatar.url }}{% endblock %}
```

My issue is that in the home page in the top the location of the image is showing as per below:
[image]

I am not sure why the image link is showing and I am not sure how to remove it.

My question is how to remove the location of the file from the page.

Answer (score 0):

This location come from this tag {{ info.avatar.url }}, just remove it and url in home page will disappear,  if you want to show the image itself instead,  you can replace it with img tag like this:

Comment: I want to keep it for the meta purposes, i want to hide it instead. The meta is used to show the image and other information when page link is sent using whatsapp of social media platforms

Comment: So in this case, you need other flag that can be examined to show or hide this url, once you have this flag then you need it to pass it to template via using context in its view,Or you can use simple tag where you can examine the request context and proceed accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to hide the url on your page like below :-

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %} {% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% block description %}{{ info.description }}{% endblock %}

<span style="display:none;">
    {% block image %}{{ info.avatar.url }}{% endblock %}
</span>
```